# Spring Roo MVC: JSTL print array of objects

Tags: java, spring, foreach, jstl, aspectj

I have a working Spring Controller class with the relevant method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="shownews", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String getNews(Model model) {

         // test
         ArrayList<String> a =new ArrayList<String>();
         a.add("aa");
         a.add("bb");
         model.addAttribute("someA", a);

         // real data 
         model.addAttribute("newsS", News.getAllNews()); // returns a valid List<News>

       return "shownews";
   }
```

Then I want to display those values in my .jsp page, code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %> 
...
VALUES: ${someA}     // output: '[aa, bb]'
VALUES: ${newsS}     // output: '[Category: categ1, Contents: cont1, Dateposted: 2011-
                                12-22 00:00:00.0, Id: 1, IdWho ........]'

<c:forEach items="${newsS}" var="someitem">
<p> Category: ${someitem.category} </p>  // output: 'Category: ', instead of  'Category: categ1'
</c:forEach>
```

It seems that the array is properly submitted to view...
The answer is: how can I list every object with its properties? (using forEach tag)
Thank you!

UPDATE:

My News.java file contains only field declarations (no getters or setters).

Some Roo generated AspectJ files:
News_Roo_Entity.aj:

```
privileged aspect News_Roo_Entity { 
  .... 
  public static List<News> News.findAllNews() { 
     return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM News o", News.class).getResultList(); 
    }
 }
```

News_Roo_JavaBean.aj:

```
 privileged aspect News_Roo_JavaBean {
     public String News.getCategory() 
     { 
         return this.category; // it's working 100%
     } 
     ... other get() methods 
  }
```

---

---

**SOLVED**

I disabled Roo in my proj (became a simple Spring) but no results...

The [trivial] problem was:
My view.jsp had the header:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<div xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"     xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:page="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:table="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" version="2.0">
.... 
</div>
```

Removed

```
<div xmlns:jsp= .... >
```

and replaced with a simple one:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-   8859-1" isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Probably it was just copy&paste from a .jspx file and a mix of xmlns and taglib...

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Show us the code of News.getCategory()

Comment: My News.java file contains only field declarations (no getters or setters).
  
I noticed that I have some roo generated ASPECTJ beans, here is News_Roo_Entity.aj:

    privileged aspect News_Roo_Entity {

        ....

        public static List<News> News.findAllNews() {
            return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM News o", News.class).getResultList();
        }
     }

And News_Roo_JavaBean.aj:
    
    privileged aspect News_Roo_JavaBean {
    
        public String News.getCategory() {
            return this.category;
        }
        ... other get() methods
   }

Comment: @user1118253: hint: you can update your question. It is much easyer to read the formated code from the question then from a comment.

Comment: @user1118253: If you want to lern Spring (without any knowlege about spring), then you should not start with Spring Roo, you should try to write the first controller without Roo.

Comment: @Ralph that is what I'm trying to do... to ignore the aspectJ code and write that .java controller

Answer (score 0):

It should work exatly how you tried: `${someitem.category}` will print the result from `toString()` of the object returned by method `News.getCategory()`.

The behavior you desciped looks like `getCategory()` returns `null` (or more unlikely: the `toString()` method return an empty string)